# Blank image with toDataURL and sketch.js

Tags: javascript, todataurl

I've just added sketch.js on my project and it works greats!
I have only one problem: I need to store the image 'sketched' in my db but if I can to try to get it I obtain a blank image :-(
How I can do it?
With this code toDataURL is always the same and represent a blank image

```
.... 
canvas = document.getElementById('canvasDiv');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = '100';
canvas.height = '50';
dataPicture = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");
newPicture = dataPicture.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '');
...
```

Comment: Did you draw anything on the canvas before calling `toDataURL()`? also, your next line is useless, you're calling the png version of the dataURL and trying to parse a jpeg one

Comment: before I use 'canvasDiv' to draw the images with sketch.js

Comment: sorry, I tried with "png" and "jpg" and when I pasted my code here I made a mistake; "jpg" or "png" doesn't work either...

Comment: So at this moment your canvas is empty, what do you expect the dataURL to return? (actually it should be something like `"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAACWCAYAAABkW7XSAAAAxUlEQVR4nO3BMQEAAADCoPVPbQhfoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOA1v9QAATX68/0AAAAASUVORK5CYII="` which is indeed an image filled of transparent pixels.

Comment: It's that.... 
Before to call the function I draw on canvasDiv an image (with the cursor using sketch.js)

Comment: (if I save the image "sketched" by right-click it is with my sketch...)

Comment: then you just have to make the call to `toDataURL()` after you drawn your sketch

Comment: already tried and it doesn't work...
example http://altamai.slalomskinevegal.it/example.html

Comment: because you are exporting to jpeg, which will transform every transparent pixels to black ones. First fill a white rect in the background, or if you want to save transparent pixels, export to png